# [ERROR] [WallTime] Unable to immediately register with master node [http://localhost:11311]: master may not be running yet

Tags: teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i got this error while trying to install teleop twist keyboard controls

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276234/%5Berror%5D-%5Bwalltime:-1511043999.000666%5D-unable-to-immediately-register-with-master-node-%5Bhttp://localhost:11311%5D:-master-may-not-be-running-yet.-will-keep-trying/) by [abhilash](https://answers.ros.org/users/31062/abhilash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-18**:
This doesn't make much sense; this is a runtime error, not something that can happen during installation. If you can update your question with the command that you're running and copy and paste the output here, we can probably help figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure to start roscore (the master node) before running any other nodes: `roscore &`

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0